# Parse a string into a date in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a string field with the format `Jan/17` - is there a way to convert this to a date? Using a cast fails the conversion. All 12 months are in a 3 character format.

Comment: With what do you talk to the SQL Server? ... .NET C#?

Comment: I'm using coldfusion.

Comment: You won't have any versions where the month name strings are in foreign languages will you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
select cast('01/' + col as date)
```

Comment: Ah brilliantly simple. I'll accept this when I can.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('Jan/17' AS DATETIME USING 'en-us')
```

even the simpler one would work:

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('Mar/28' AS DATETIME)
```

Note that this function relies on the presence of the .NET Framework Common Language Runtime (CLR). So Gordon's solution is better in case you want a SQL-only way of doing it.

Comment: It doesn't recognize the command, maybe because my sql server  is out of date?

Comment: Was available in SQL Server 2012. Not sure of earlier versions.